# What is the difference between Mirror based reflection and traditional reflection?

Tags: reflection, programming-languages, dart, language-design, dart-mirrors

Some languages like Dart use mirror based reflection so, in simple terms, what is the difference between such implementation and traditional reflection as you see in C# or Java.

Update:
I found this excellent (and somewhat quirky) video by Gilad Bracha on Mirror based reflection in Newspeak.
http://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/hirschfeld/events/past/media/100105_Bracha_2010_LinguisticReflectionViaMirrors_HPI.mp4 (mirror stuff starts at 7:42)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For many uses, I don't think mirrors will be that different than Java reflection. The most important thing understand about mirrors is that they decouple the reflection API from the standard object API, so instead of obj.getClass() you use reflect(obj). It's a seemingly small difference, but it gives you a few nice things:

1. The object API isn't polluted, and there's no danger of breaking reflection by overriding a reflective method.
2. You can potentially have different mirror systems. Say, one that doesn't allow access to private methods. This could end up being very useful for tools.
3. The mirror system doesn't have to be included. For compiling to JS this can be important. If mirrors aren't used then there's no out-of-band to access code and pruning becomes viable.
4. Mirrors can be made to work on remote code, not just local code, since you don't need the reflected object to be in the same Isolate or VM as the mirror.

Here's how mirrors are different than reflection in Java and Javascript when used to get an object's methods:

Java:

```
myObject.getClass().getMethods(); // returns an array
```

Dart:

```
reflect(myObject).type.methods; // returns a map
```

Javascript:

```
var methods = [];
for (var m in myObject) {
  if (typeof m === 'function') {
    methods.push(m);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is [this article by Gilad Bracha](http://bracha.org/mirrors.pdf), Dart's co-designer and specification author. To get a glimpse, it will probably be enough to read the first chapter.

The abstract claims that mirrors adhere to three necessary principles that aren't followed by traditional reflection:

> We identify three design principles for reflection and metaprogramming
>   facilities in object oriented programming languages.  **Encapsulation:**
>   meta-level facilities must encapsulate their implementation.
>   **Stratification:** meta-level facilities must be separated from
>   base-level functionality.  **Ontological correspondence:** the ontology of
>   meta-level facilities should correspond to the ontology of the
>   language they manipulate. *Traditional/mainstream reflective
>   architectures do not follow these precepts.* In contrast, reflective
>   APIs built around the concept of mirrors are characterized by
>   adherence to these three principles.

Answer (score 1):

I would also point you to this other recent answer by Gilad, where he lists some other great reference material: [How to get concrete object of a static method via mirror API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113647/how-to-get-concrete-object-of-a-static-method-via-mirror-api)

Comment: Thanks John. I did see those links before. I was hoping to quickly get a summary or a gist rather than reading the paper.

Comment: Many of the differences, in my view, are at the software engineering level, and not so interesting to those of us who write software on top of them.  Using mirrors feels easier to me than my experience with the .net reflection API.